# JSTree binding my own click event

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree, and would like to bind my own click event to each of the nodes....

This is what i am trying....

```
     $("#demo1").jstree({
   "core": { "initially_open": ["root"] },
   "html_data": {
     "data": out
   },
   "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"]
 }).bind("select_node.jstree", 
function (e, data) 
{ 
  alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));     });
```

I am using the HTML_Plugin, setting the out variable to look like this

```
"<li id='root'><a href='#'>Root node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child node</a></li></ul></li>"
```

trouble is, the click event does not appear to be firing, as i do not see the alert message.

Please show me the error in my ways.

thanks
tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $("#demo1").jstree({
   "core": { "initially_open": ["root"] },
   "html_data": {
     "data": out
   },
   "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui"]
 }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
   var id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
   var parent = data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
   if (parent == -1) {
     alert(id);
   } else {
     alert(parent.find('a').first().text() + "|" + id);
   }
 });
```

One thing was needed... addition of the plug in UI

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following attribute from your code and try, the out variable would give you "out not defined error."

```
          "html_data": {
             "data": out
           },
```

Comment: This post is very low quality, and doesn't make a lot of sense in it's current form. please update with proper formatting and explanation.

Comment: Thank you! and i will do the same.